# How to iterate over an array within an object if the object meets certain conditions?

Tags: jquery, each

I want to achieve the functionality of:

Iterate over the array in the object where `k1`'s value is `woo hoo!`.

The following works but i'm not sure it's the best way because I think it would need to loop over each object before it found a match.

**Array**

```
myArray = [{"k1": "woo hoo!", "k2": ["k2_1","k2_2","k2_3"], "k3": ["k3_v1"]},{"k1": "boo", "k2": ["k2_v1"], "k3": ["k3_v1"]}]
```

**jQuery**

```
$.each(myArray, function (obj, v) {
    $.each(v.k2, function (i, value) {
        if (v.k1 == "woo hoo!") {
            alert(value);
        }
    });
});
```

The following contains this example as well as a few other commented out examples I have used to understand `$.each` more.

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/MnASV/5/

Comment: don't use alert for debugging use `console.log()` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PPrxZ/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only change you have to do is to move teh if condition out of the second loop.

In your case the `k1` belongs to the outer object, but you are iterating through the second loop even of the value is not matching that can be avoided by checking it before.

```
// iterate over array within each object
$.each(myArray_1, function (obj, v) {
    if (v.k1 == "woo hoo!") {
        $.each(v.k2, function (i, value) {
            console.log(value);
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PPrxZ/)

Comment: If there were many objects in the top level array, it seems it would need to iterate over each one and then perform the actions associated with the matching `if` condition.  I was wondering if there was a quicker and more direct way to define at the top level `"only iterate over an object with this certain property?"`.  So something like `iterate over this where foo == bar`?

Comment: Your response has gotten several upvotes whilst I was writing my comment so I am guessing not, thanks for the answer - can accept in 3 minutes.

Comment: @user1063287 AFAIK there is no property like that... you can look at [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) even that iterates through each element to find whether it satisfies the condition

Comment: @user1063287 don't always trust the upvotes!!! or for the matter downvotes... there could be another solution that I'm not aware of....